# How can i enable and disable android:singleLine dynamically?

Tags: android

How can i enable and disable android:singleLine dynamically?I have a listview, i want to make some items in listView with text singleLine true and some sinleLine false?pls help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextView.setSingleLine(boolean);